# Passing a derived class to a function taking a base class in SWIG Python

Tags: python, swig

I am passing a derived class into a function taking a base class using Python 3.3 and SWIG 2.0.10.

The same SWIG .i file is being used for C# and it works well.  However, in Python, SWIG reports that there is no C++ method accepting the derived type - only a method accepting the base type.  That statement is true, but I need to pass the derived type and have SWIG direct the call as if it was the base type.

The derived type does not exist in C++.  It only exists in Python (and C#).  However, we have directors enabled and, as stated, it is working fine in C#.

Same result in Python 2.6 and 2.7.

C++

```
class Base {};
// Note: there is NO "class Derived" in C++.
void f(Base* a) { ... }
```

Python

```
class Derived(Base): pass

x = Derived()
f(x) # SWIG runtime error - In C++ there is no f(Derived*) - there is only f(Base*)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that in class Derived I did not properly call Base.__init__().

Once I fixed that, the polymorphism in Swig just worked.

```
class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Derived, self).__init__()
```